# curl русские символы в url

Tags: c++, curl

каким образом можно открыть курлом сайт с русскими символами в url?

```
string url("http://usabili.ru/news/2009/09/08/Русский_язык_в_URL.html");

char *output = curl_easy_escape(curl, url.data(), url.length());
if (output) {
url = output;
curl_free(output);
}
url = ReplaceAll(url, "%3A", ":");
url = ReplaceAll(url, "%2F", "/");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
```

Такой вариант не сработал.
Если же скопировать url из хрома и поставить его вместо запроса, то все работает

Comment: Всё зависит от кодировки. Скорее всего там будет UTF-8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iconv/iconv.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <curl/curl.h>


using namespace std;

int convertCharset(string inStr, string& outStr, char* fromCharset, char* toCharset, bool clearOutStr = true)
{
    libiconv_t cd;

    cd = libiconv_open(toCharset, fromCharset);
    if (cd == (libiconv_t)(-1))
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("convertCharset: Could not open handle iconv");
    }

    size_t inSize = inStr.size();
    const char* in = inStr.data();


    vector<char> outBuf(1000);
    char* out;
    size_t outSize;

    bool badWord = false;
    while (inSize > 0 && badWord == false)
    {
        errno = 0;

        out = outBuf.data();
        outSize = outBuf.size();

        size_t k = libiconv(cd, &in, &inSize, &out, &outSize);
        if (k == (size_t)-1)
        {
            switch (errno)
            {
            case EINVAL:
                badWord = true;//cannot convert all data, not the full character
                break;
            case E2BIG:
                //out buff small
                break;
            case NULL:
                break;
            default:
                throw std::runtime_error(string("convertCharset: error:") + to_string(errno) + " in byte №" + to_string(inStr.size() - inSize));
            }
        }

        if (clearOutStr) { outStr.clear(); }

        int parsedBytes = outBuf.size() - outSize;
        outStr.append(outBuf.begin(), outBuf.begin() + parsedBytes);
    }

    if (iconv_close(cd) != 0)
        std::runtime_error("convertCharset: Could not close handle iconv");

    return inSize;
}

std::string replaceAll(std::string str, const std::string& from, const std::string& to) {
    size_t start_pos = 0;
    while ((start_pos = str.find(from, start_pos)) != std::string::npos) {
        str.replace(start_pos, from.length(), to);
        start_pos += to.length(); // Handles case where 'to' is a substring of 'from'
    }
    return str;
}

void main()
{

    string url("http://usabili.ru/news/2009/09/08/Русский_язык_в_URL.html");

    try {
        convertCharset(url, url, "CP1251", "UTF-8");
    }
    catch (std::exception e)
    {
        cout << e.what() << endl;
    }

    CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
    char *output = curl_easy_escape(curl, url.data(), url.length());
    if (output) {
        url = output;
        curl_free(output);
    }
    url = replaceAll(url, "%3A", ":");
    url = replaceAll(url, "%2F", "/");

    cout << url << endl;


    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);

    ...
}
```

Собственно, в curl_easy_escape нужно посылать UTF-8 изначально.